# В каком падеже употребить название?

Tags: названия

Можно ли при желании выразиться след. образом:

Я бы назвал эту вещь "сталеварка".

В некоторых кругах ее называют "опасный предмет".

Comment: Названия (наименования) достойны начинаться с прописной.

Answer (score 1):

Ну какое двоеточие, какая "прямая речь"?!

Можно, можно и при желании, и без желания "выразиться след. образом"!

Именительный хорош, творительный именно что при большом желании, факультативно.

---

Немного лирики с физикой - из "Науки и жизни":

[Есть ли разница в таких предложениях: "Он был дворник" - "Он был дворником"? Можно ли считать их взаимозаменяемыми?](https://www.nkj.ru/archive/articles/4001/)

> Вопрос читателя напомнил мне пушкинские строки из "Евгения Онегина":
>   "Ее сестра звалась Татьяна..." Почему же эта форма сказуемого, в
>   котором существительное стоит в именительном падеже, не врезалась в
>   нашу память так, как другая - с творительным падежом существительного:
>   "Итак, она звалась Татьяной"?
>
> Великий поэт не нарушил правил грамматики: действительно, оба варианта
>   в то время были одинаково употребительны. Правда, для нас именительный
>   падеж в подобной конструкции кажется устаревшей формой. Сравните: "В
>   то время был еще жених ее супруг" (мы бы сказали "был женихом"); "Нет,
>   пускай послужит в армии, ... да будет солдат..." (Пушкин). Еще пример:
>   "Он решил, что женитьба на Элен была бы несчастье" (Лев Толстой).
>
> Как видите, такие формы сказуемого архаизовались.
>
> Однако в современном русском языке все же продолжают употребляться
>   варианты форм именного сказуемого, которые отличаются по значению:
>   именительный падеж существительного при отвлеченной связке *(быть)*
>   подчеркивает протяженность во времени указанного признака, свойства.
>   Сравним: *Моя подруга была артистка* (это ее постоянная профессия) и
>   *Она была артисткой* (какое-то время, а потом стала педагогом).
>
> Если же связка отсутствует *(Пушкин - поэт)*, то именное сказуемое,
>   выраженное существительным в именительном падеже, - единственно
>   возможная в литературном языке форма. Замена же именительного падежа
>   творительным придает речи разговорную окраску. Например: *Давно ты
>   здесь рыбаком?* (Тургенев); *Я снова посудником на пароходе "Пермь"*
>   (Горький).

**[подробности](https://www.nkj.ru/archive/articles/4001/)**

Answer (score 1):

В толковом словаре:
[**назва́ть**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x) *св. кого-что (**кем-чем*** или ***кто-что***).
1. Дать название, имя и т. п. кому-либо, чему-либо.
Назвали сына Андреем, а дочь Ольгой. Щенка назвали Шарик. Назвали яхту "Звезда".
// Определить, охарактеризовать каким-либо словом. Её можно назвать красавицей.

В словаре управления:
[**назвать**](http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/punctuation-rosental/fc/slovar-205-1.htm#zag-929) [дать имя, название и т. п.] сочетается с имен. и твор. падежами (**кто-что / кем-чем**).
Мордочка у телёнка беленькая, назвать бы Беляночка или Снежная (Пан.); Назвали село Троица; Новорождённая дочь Анны, названная тоже Анной, заболела (Л. Т.); Назвали сопку Вертушкой.

Словари не дают разъяснений, какой падеж предпочтительнее, поэтому выбор, думаю, зависит от контекста. (Как пример: *Я назову планету именем твоим...* Здесь возможен только Т. п.)

*Я бы назвал эту вещь **сталеварка/сталеваркой.**

В некоторых кругах ее называют **опасный предмет / опасным предметом.***
[Так как слова *сталеварка* в словарях нет, берем его в кавычки — если подразумевается какое-то свое (особенное) значение, и без кавычек — если это образное название мартеновской печи.]

*Автор назвал эту пьесу «Прелюдией». Я бы назвал её «Судьба»!* (А. Вербицкая)
*Я бы назвал эту вещь сном о России...* (В. Бондаренко)

Answer (score 1):

Глагол НАЗВАТЬ - это глагол с двойным управлением. Управляемыми падежами при беспредложном двойном управлении могут быть падежи: а) вин. и дат.; б) вин. и тв.; в) род. и тв.; г) дат. и тв.

В вашем примере лучше всего использовать форму творительного падежа, можно с кавычками и без кавычек:

***Я бы назвал эту вещь сталеваркой.***

***В некоторых кругах её называют опасным предметом.***

Но с использованием кавычек возможна форма "сталеварка", "опасный предмет". Стиль разговорный, почему бы нет?

Answer (score 0):

Если "сталеварка", то это уже прямая речь, и перед ней логично поставить двоеточие.А "сталеваркой" тоже можно написать, но тогда без двоеточия.